# Basic hive insert job failing to work, getting error "Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127. Error file: prelaunch.err."

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce

```
hive> insert into test.emp (sr_no,usr_name,city) values (10,"Prince","Kathmandu");
Query ID = princemehta_20230311033859_3d7f53f2-3523-4a8b-840d-fcb6aa8729cd
Total jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1678480813847_0014, Tracking URL = http://Princes-MacBook-Air.local:8088/proxy/application_1678480813847_0014/
Kill Command = /usr/local/opt/hadoop/libexec/bin/mapred job  -kill job_1678480813847_0014
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
2023-03-11 03:39:11,840 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_1678480813847_0014 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Job Tracking URL: http://Princes-MacBook-Air.local:8088/cluster/app/application_1678480813847_0014
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

Was trying to run a insert query. getting error in logs as ,

[2023-03-11 03:39:10.914]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127. Error file: prelaunch.err.

Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :

Last 4096 bytes of stderr :

/bin/bash: /Library/Internet: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

HDFS does not include a /Library folder, as would a macOS machine.

Change your Hive settings, or table definitions to not reference Mac specific file paths

Comment: Hey, I’m really new to hadoop and hive could you tell me …how exactly should I change that. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how you installed or started Hadoop, but you can find files on your system called `core-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml`, or `hive-site.xml` that configure the filesystem paths that are used

Comment: @OneCricketeer is it possible that the problem is (also?) caused by the presence of spaces in the path? Because I think the process is trying to access `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins` but it stops before the space (I have the same problem :D)

Comment: @Gatto99 That's correct. That's where Java is installed? I suggest using sdkman or asdf-java instead of downloading Java from Oracle

Comment: Yes, it is. I'll try to use one of them or install java using homebrew. Thanks for the advice, I'll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in a comment, I think the problem is caused by the space in a folder's name (i.e. `Internet Plug-Ins`) present in the path where java is located.

To avoid that, I followed this [guide](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.html) to uninstall Java and then I installed OpenJDK using Homebrew (you can also use [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/) or [asdf-java](https://github.com/halcyon/asdf-java) instead of downloading Java from Oracle as suggested by @OneCricketeer)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar issue, the $JAVA_HOME variable which was set to /Library/internet Plug-Ins/.... should be replaced with Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/{jdk-version}.jdk/Contents/Home and update the $JAVA_HOME record on hadoop-env.sh to reflect the new $JAVA_HOME path, then stop and restart hadoop and it should work perfectly now.